# Promise not resolving Express

Tags: node.js, express, async-await, es6-promise

I am learning node.js and trying to make HTTP calls via Express. I have the following function which when it reaches the promise it throws an error that I see in Postman "error socket hangup", evidently my understanding of Promises is probably skewed here. So any pointers on what I am doing wrong would really help.

**Index.ts**

```
    let user = await getUser("2");

    async function getUser(id: string) {
        return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
            api.get('myserver/api/users?user=' + id, function (req, res) {
                console.log(res);
                if (res) {
                    resolve(res);
                } else {
                    reject("error");
                }
            });
        })
    }
```

I do not get any socket hangup when using axios like so:

```
     return axios.get('myserver/api/users?users=' + id, {
             headers: { 'content-type': 'application/json' }
         })
         .then((response) => {
             console.log(response);
             return response.data;
         });
```

So I would like to learn what is it that I am doing incorrectly

Comment: maybe you're doing the Postman request wrongly? like, not setting the content-type, hitting the wrong URL? if axios works, but postman doesn't, I'm pretty sure there's something wrong with the way postman tries to make the request

Comment: The only thing visbily different between axios and express is that the content type is missing. But I am wondering whether I have set up the promise correctly?

Comment: yes, that looks right. If that `api.get(...)` has a for that returns a promise, things could be written to look a bit simpler, but otherwise, this looks correct.

Comment: an observation: since your function returns a promise, there's no need to declare it as `async`

Comment: ah ok, thanks. But in the parent I must defined async to "await" it make sense